# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Microsoft.Kinect.KinectSensor.Start()'

Tags: c#-4.0, kinect-sdk

I have this function, showing an error message when compiled.

> " An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Microsoft.Kinect.KinectSensor.Start()' "

And unable to solve it. Please help.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

            Microsoft.Kinect.KinectSensor.Start();

        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Runtime initialization failed. " +
               "Please make sure Kinect device is plugged in.");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for all

Comment: have you readed some documentation before do this code?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a static instance of the KinectSensor like below and then start the device :

```
public static KinectSensor ksensor;
...
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

        ksensor.Start();

    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Runtime initialization failed. " +
           "Please make sure Kinect device is plugged in.");
        return;
    }
}
```

Try this and it should work.
Also, it would be better to create a start method to use it inside the Form1_Load

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to find an instance of KinectSensor?

e.g.

```
KinectSensor sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors
                              .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Status == KinectStatus.Connected);
sensor.Start();
```